# Proving the invariance of the inner product

Tags: vectors, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, covariance

If we define the inner product as ${\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{v}=g_{ij}u^{i}v^{j}}$, where ${g_{ij}}$ is the metric tensor, ${S}$ and ${T}$ are transformation matrices, ${S}$-for covariant indices and ${T}$-for contravariant (obviously ${ST=I}$). How do we prove that the inner product is invariant? I tried this way:
$${T^{a}_{i}T^{b}_{j}g_{ij}u^{i}v^{j}S^{i}_{a}S^{j}_{b}=\delta^{a}_{a}\delta^{b}_{b}g_{ij}u^{i}v^{j}}$$ 
which is not good expression moreover in the beginning I multiply by tensor with index that is already dummy which is not right. Is there a way to prove it with this kind of transformations?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  The equation seems to be nonsense, as you seemed to know yourself, but the words aren't specific enough to know what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by rewriting the scalar product as a covariant-contravariant contraction, like so:
$$
{\bf u}\cdot{\bf v} = g_{ij}u^iv^j = (g_{ij}u^i)v^j = u_jv^j
$$
Now transform the components with your $S$ and $T$ matrices,
$$
u_jv^j = \left( S_j^a {\bar u}_a \right) \left( T^j_b {\bar v}^b \right) = (S_j^a T^j_b) {\bar u}_a {\bar v}^b = \delta^a_b {\bar u}_a {\bar v}^b = {\bar u}_b {\bar v}^b
$$ 
and reintroduce the metric tensor to obtain
$$
g_{ij}u^iv^j = g_{ab}{\bar u}^a {\bar v}^b, \;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\; {\bf u}\cdot{\bf v} = \bar{{\bf u}}\cdot\bar{{\bf v}}
$$
I may have redefined the direction of your $S$ and $T$ in the process, but this conveys the gist of it.